# Stuck in DatachannelInterface

Tags: c++, webrtc

I use a self compile webrtc source in cpp. Reagulary when I use DataChannel after reconnection, my program just stuck.

Here is the debug I have:

```
    Thread 13 (Thread 0x7f3f39a33700 (LWP 819)):
#0  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:185
#1  0x000055a8542d4d05 in rtc::Event::Wait(int, int) ()
#2  0x000055a85451f630 in webrtc::DataChannelProxyWithInternal<webrtc::DataChannelInterface>::reliable() const ()
#3  0x000055a854234c4f in DataChannelInterfaceManager::reliable (this=0x7f3f00006af0) at ./PeerConnectionManager.h:100
```

What is that rtc::Event::Wait function and why the program just stuck with no errors?

```
  rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::DataChannelInterface> dataChannel;

....

  bool
  reliable(void) {
    if (dataChannel.get() == nullptr) {
      RTC_LOG(LERROR) << __LINE__;
      return false;
    }
    return dataChannel->reliable(); // Freeze here
  }
```

I also add the complete log from gdb

https://pastebin.com/YGE5qUPi

Comment: *just stuck* can you be more clear ? how long is it ? *after reconnection* are you sure your 'reconnection' is correct ? you do not give code ...

Comment: I have to restart the program. It doesn't continue after that.  This happens after 20 our 30 connection/deconnection.

Comment: Your program is threaded.  The program is waiting for 'something'. It suffers from deadlock.

Comment: This is also what I think. It seems it is more  webrtc thread than my program which is is in deadlock.How to known where is the trouble?